# How can I compute $A(v_1 + v_2)$ where $v_1$ and $v_2$ are eigenvectors of the matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> If $v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}5\\3\end{bmatrix}$ and $v_2 = \begin{bmatrix}3\\1\end{bmatrix}$ are eigenvectors of a matrix $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = -1$ and $\lambda_2 = 4$ respectively, then
>
> $A(v_1 + v_2)= ?$
>
> What about $A(3v_1) = ?$

I get what I'm doing wrong. I did $v_1 + v_2 = \begin{bmatrix}5\\3\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}3\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}8\\4\end{bmatrix}$ then I did $A(\begin{bmatrix}8\\4\end{bmatrix})= \begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&4\end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix}8\\4\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-8\\16\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Hint. Do not add up the vectors first. You must first examine the multiplication $Av=\lambda{v}$ on both $v1$ and $v2$. And your eigenvalues are given....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A$ is only diagonal with respect to a basis of eigenvectors, namely $v_1$ and $v_2$, not the standard basis, which is why your computation fails. Try using linearity and the definition of eigenvectors instead:

$A(v_1+v_2)=Av_1+Av_2=\lambda_1 v_1+\lambda_2 v_2$

Similarly for $A(3v_1)$.

Comment: I did that and got the same answer.

Comment: You must have made an error. Did you compute $-v_1+4v_2$?

Comment: You're correct. I failed to see the property you were showing. I see it now and got (7,1) for the first one and (-15,-9) for the second. Thanks